# How to make child fragments inherit bottom navigation bar from parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm building an app using Android's Architecture Components in which I use the Navigation Component (with nav controller) to navigate to different destination fragments within my app. I currently have a navigation drawer defined in my Main Activity from which any of the child fragments can access through the toolbar. I want to implement a bottom navigation bar on one of my child fragments so that any of the destinations from that child fragment inherit its bottom nav bar. [Here's a beautiful drawing illustrating what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgwqk.png)

So my question is essentially how do I make child fragments inherit a layout item from their parent? Would I need create an activity instead of Child Fragment 2 to host the bottom nav bar?

Comment: I'm pretty new to navigation components. I think your last idea is probably correct that you will need to create an activity to host the bottom nav bar and all fragments that use it.